# Anonymous Software to bypass ISP filters

Tags: software-rec, proxy, isp, privacy

I need a software that enables me to anonymously bypass an ISP filter -- I need my IP and location to be anonymous so that I can surf the Internet freely. I used to use UltraSurF but it was blocked by the ISP.

If any one knows or uses a small and quickly connecting software like UltraSurf, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both come for free and are relatively easy to set up:

---

#### [Tor – The Onion Router](https://www.torproject.org/)

> Tor is free software and an open network that helps you defend against a form of network surveillance that threatens personal freedom and privacy

It basically routes your traffic over several other nodes in the Tor network. In order to get started, download it from the link above, then follow the installation tutorials ([Windows](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-windows.html.en), [OS X](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en), [Linux](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en)). The best

---

#### [Hotspot Shield](http://hotspotshield.com/)

> Hotspot Shield protects your entire web surfing session; securing your connection at both your home Internet network & Public Internet networks (both wired and wireless). [...] Hotspot Shield also makes you private online making your identity invisible to third party websites and ISP’s.

This software is available for Windows and OS X only. It connects to a VPN – so if your ISP knows about it, they might be able to block it just like they did with UltraSurf.

Comment: both of them are blocked too , I just can't understand what they did , it takes so long time to connect and at the end it fails , is there another programs ?

Comment: Hm, weird -- Tor *should* work. There's a long list at: [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/tor/)

Comment: I'll try Tor with brideges

Comment: So did that work for you?

Comment: I tried Tor and its bridges , but they block them too ? some progs. you add work in some countries without others , do you know a program works in this list ?

Comment: FreeGate works , it seems great but he told me :Usage of DynaWeb and Freegate is limited to users in China (CN). Our database indicates that your IP 77.44.**.** is from **. You usage of this service is denied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use premium VPNS to effectivly tunnel all your traffic through your ISP to the VPN company and then out from there to where ever you want.

Comment: you mean paid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use encrypted SSH tunnels or VPNs that create a tunnel from your PC to other servers, to redirect your traffic. There are good services that allow you to surf anonymously, unblock any site and service like SKype, etc.
Here are more details for review:  http://blog.pirateray.com/post/35136605543/pirateray-and-vpn-review

Answer (score 0):

Use Free VPN (OpenVPN,L2TP,PPTP,SSTP) services. Goto this link http://www.vpngratis.net/ where you can get updates about FREEVPNs.